# Does PHP handle new timezones such as New Zealand's UTC + 14:00?

Tags: php, date, timezone

I was going through Wikipedia and found out that New Zealand skipped a day (December 30 2011) and so did Somoa which pushed them into a timezone ahead. So, a part of New Zealand is now UTC + 14:00. Samoa which used to be in UTC + 11 is now +12. Does PHP adjust to support this change.

Comment: I don't believe New Zealand skipped a day, actually - I believe it was just Samoa. New Zealand is +12/+13, whereas Samoa (Pacific/Apia) went from UTC-10 to UTC+14, hence skipping a day. (It's now UTC+13/14 depending on DST.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of that comment was. It seems to just back up my assertions, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [PHP List of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). The New Zealand timezone is contained in the [Others](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) list as `NZ`.

You can set the default timezone this way:

```
date_default_timezone_set('NZ');
```

> Instead of using this function to set the default timezone in your
>   script, you can also use the INI setting date.timezone to set the
>   default timezone.

Comment: The link goes to a list of timezone's where New Zealand's is not readily apparent. Also StackOverflow recommends that answers be more than just a link; in this case including the time zone might be more helpful.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As per the note on the PHP Timezones/Other page (where timezone `NZ` is listed, and as mentioned by `user2070775`, `*Warning*: Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons, and may expose erroneous behavior.` The correct timezone is listed here, http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.pacific.php

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is wrong and it may cause failure in your application in the future.

The PHP documentation clearly recommends not to use "NZ" as the timezone, because it is there

> for backward compatibility only

Please use `Pacific/Auckland` instead. Note that New Zeland has many territories with different timezones (Tokelau, Cook Islands, etc)

Comment: Agreed. Accepted answer is incorrect. Marking yours up. The correct timezone (as provided by `user2070775` is listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.pacific.php

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini file, set
date.timezone = 'Pacific/Auckland'

Comment: Any documentation reference on this?